# 500 error for PHP script with cron, but not CLI

Tags: php, cron

I have a PHP script which I am trying to run via cron. In cron I have

> php /home/dir/dir/foo.php

When the command runs, the cron log says:

> Status: 500 Internal Server Error
>
> X-Powered-By: PHP/7.1.16
>
> Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

However, if I simply run php /home/dir/dir/foo.php from the command line, it runs just fine with no error.

I have another PHP script in the same directory which runs correctly via cron.

Other info: The script which isn't working is located outside the document root, creates a database connection, and connects to an API.

I don't have much experience with cron, so I probably set something up wrong, but I'm puzzled why the same command would work via CLI but not in cron.

Comment: You are executing php as cli in cron and get HTTP response? Could you please show whole crontab line?

Comment: The whole crontab line is: 0,15,30,45 * * * * php /home/dir/dir/get_emails.php >/dev/null 2>&1

Comment: And cron log says something? This part `>/dev/null 2>&1` writes any output to /dev/null, so this should not be in any log. Are you sure, that this error comes from this script?

Comment: Oh, sorry to be confusing. I rewrote the line to write to an error log, but I posted the version where it wen to /dev/null. Actually, I just figured out the answer myself. See answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out the answer. I changed "php" in the crontab entry to point instead to the PHP 7.1 path, and it's working now.

> 0,15,30,45 * * * * /opt/alt/php71/usr/bin/php /home/dir/dir/get_emails.php >/dev/null 2>&1

I would have thought that php in CLI would be the same version as php in cron, but apparently not.

Comment: It depends on how you have PHP installed and if you even have multiple versions of PHP on the system.  If you have multiples, then the `$PATH` comes into play (and the various `ini` files, etc once the specific PHP binary has been found)